# jquery mobile input text field help text or popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jqueryform

Is there a support for 'Help Text' or Popup link for form input elements in Jquery Mobile ?

This must be a common problem and I am wondering if there is out-of-the-box support for this already.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Popups? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link. Looks good and might suffice for your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no, take in consideration, JQM was built with mobile platforms in mind and classic popups and help texts can not be used on mobile phones (no mouse over or such event).

Only similar functionality is dialog box:

```
<a href="dialog.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Open dialog</a>
```

This example was taken from [here](http://brooky.cc/2011/04/23/jquery-mobile-cheat-sheet/). Unfortunately it can be used as standard help text/popup.

On the other hand JQM is compatible with jQuery UI plugins so you can always look to use some of them, take a look [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/).

If you are building mobile app use both options with [taphold](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) event, in case of classic desktop web app you can still use mouse events and in this case use second option and pick yourself a popup plugin.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links Gajotres.. This helps me very much.